# How to use array in kibana elastic search?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, kibana

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "phoneNumber": {
        "query": [
          "7738845133",
          "9876765434",
          "8765874532"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have this code written to search for multiple phone numbers, but it is not taking multiple phone number but works fine with a single phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html), to search on multiple phone numbers

Try out this below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "phoneNumber": [
        "7738845133",
        "9876765434",
        "8765874532"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Debangana Debray did you get a chance to go through the answer looking forward to get feedback from you :-)